# working with ExpandableListView with XML and code

Tags: android-layout, expandablelistview, expandablelistadapter

I was just trying to create few groups and its corresponding children in an activity. No success so far. Tried various suggestions given by people in different questions but they have failed to get my code work. Probably, i ain't clear on the concept and doing something which isn't solving my problem !

I want to specify the layout of the expandablelistview, groupview and childview via XML.  I want to manipulate data through the code. Currently, i am using BaseExpandableListAdpater but in future i want it work with SimpleCursorTreeAdapter too.

Below is the code i have written :

1) menuitems.xml - the actual ExpandableListView

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <!-- Menu Title -->
    <!-- <TextView  android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text="Menu Categories"
                android:textSize="20sp"/> -->

    <!-- Menu sorted according to the categories -->
    <ExpandableListView android:id="@android:id/list"
                        android:layout_height="fill_parent" 
                        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                        >
    </ExpandableListView>

</LinearLayout>
```

2)group_list.xml - layout to populate the group i.e. the parent

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:orientation="vertical"
  android:layout_width="fill_parent"
  android:layout_height="fill_parent">

  <TextView android:id="@+id/groupListId"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent" 
            android:textSize="15dp"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="group"
  />

</LinearLayout>
```

3)child_list.xml - the child list corresponding to the parent(group_list.xml)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:orientation="vertical"
  android:layout_width="fill_parent"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content">

  <TextView android:id="@+id/childListId"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
            android:textSize="20dp"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="child"
  />

</LinearLayout>
```

4)FoodieActivity.java

```
public class FoodieActivity extends ExpandableListActivity {
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */

    ExpandableListView expandableMenuCategories = null;
    ExpandableListAdapter expandableListMenuAdapter = null;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.menuitems);

        expandableMenuCategories = getExpandableListView();

        expandableListMenuAdapter = new MyMenuCategoriesAdapter();

        setListAdapter(expandableListMenuAdapter);
        registerForContextMenu(expandableMenuCategories);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreateContextMenu(ContextMenu menu, View v,
            ContextMenuInfo menuInfo) 
    {
        //TODO
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onContextItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return super.onContextItemSelected(item);
    }

    public class MyMenuCategoriesAdapter extends BaseExpandableListAdapter
    {

            String[] categoryGroups = {"One,Two,Three"};
        String[][] categoryItems = {{"Number","Integer"},{"Float","Double"},{"short,byte"}};

        @Override
        public Object getChild(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
            return categoryItems[groupPosition][childPosition];
        }

        @Override
        public long getChildId(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
            return childPosition;
        }

        @Override
        public View getChildView(int groupPosition, int childPosition,
                boolean isLastChild, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) 
        {
//          TextView childView = null;

            convertView = ((LayoutInflater.from(FoodieActivity.this)).inflate(R.layout.child_list, null));
            convertView = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.childListId);
//          TextView childView = new TextView(FoodieActivity.this);
//          childView.setLayoutParams(expandableMenuCategories.getLayoutParams());
            ((TextView)convertView).setText(getChild(groupPosition, childPosition).toString());

            return convertView;
        }

        @Override
        public int getChildrenCount(int groupPosition) {
            return categoryItems[groupPosition].length;
        }

        @Override
        public Object getGroup(int groupPosition) {
            return categoryGroups[groupPosition];
        }

        @Override
        public int getGroupCount() {
            return categoryGroups.length;
        }

        @Override
        public long getGroupId(int groupPosition) {
            return categoryGroups[groupPosition].length();
        }

        @Override
        public View getGroupView(int groupPosition, boolean isExpanded,
                View convertView, ViewGroup parent) 
        {
//          TextView groupView = null;
            try
            {
                convertView = ((LayoutInflater.from(FoodieActivity.this)).inflate(R.layout.group_list,parent, false));
                convertView = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.groupListId);
//              TextView groupView = new TextView(FoodieActivity.this);
//              groupView.setLayoutParams(expandableMenuCategories.getLayoutParams());
                ((TextView)convertView).setText(getGroup(groupPosition).toString());
            }
            catch(ClassCastException cce)
            {
                Log.d(cce.toString(), cce.getMessage());
            }

            return convertView;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean hasStableIds() {
            return true;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean isChildSelectable(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
            return true;
        }

    }
}
```

When i run this particular code i get a `ClassCast` exception :

```
09-06 18:29:11.145: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1031): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
09-06 18:29:11.145: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1031): java.lang.ClassCastException: android.widget.LinearLayout$LayoutParams
09-06 18:29:11.145: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1031):     at android.widget.ListView.setupChild(ListView.java:1761)
09-06 18:29:11.145: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1031):     at android.widget.ListView.makeAndAddView(ListView.java:1730)
09-06 18:29:11.145: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1031):     at android.widget.ListView.fillDown(ListView.java:652)
09-06 18:29:11.145: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1031):     at android.widget.ListView.fillFromTop(ListView.java:709)
09-06 18:29:11.145: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1031):     at android.widget.ListView.layoutChildren(ListView.java:1580)
09-06 18:29:11.145: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1031):     at android.widget.AbsListView.onLayout(AbsListView.java:1147)
09-06 18:29:11.145: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1031):     at android.view.View.layout(View.java:7035)
09-06 18:29:11.145: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1031):     at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1249)
09-06 18:29:11.145: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1031):     at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1125)
09-06 18:29:11.145: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1031):     at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1042)
09-06 18:29:11.145: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1031):     at android.view.View.layout(View.java:7035)
09-06 18:29:11.145: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1031):     at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:333)
09-06 18:29:11.145: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1031):     at android.view.View.layout(View.java:7035)
09-06 18:29:11.145: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1031):     at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1249)
09-06 18:29:11.145: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1031):     at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1125)
09-06 18:29:11.145: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1031):     at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1042)
09-06 18:29:11.145: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1031):     at android.view.View.layout(View.java:7035)
09-06 18:29:11.145: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1031):     at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:333)
09-06 18:29:11.145: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1031):     at android.view.View.layout(View.java:7035)
09-06 18:29:11.145: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1031):     at android.view.ViewRoot.performTraversals(ViewRoot.java:1045)
09-06 18:29:11.145: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1031):     at android.view.ViewRoot.handleMessage(ViewRoot.java:1727)
09-06 18:29:11.145: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1031):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
09-06 18:29:11.145: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1031):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
09-06 18:29:11.145: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1031):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4627)
09-06 18:29:11.145: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1031):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
09-06 18:29:11.145: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1031):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
09-06 18:29:11.145: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1031):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:868)
09-06 18:29:11.145: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1031):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:626)
09-06 18:29:11.145: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1031):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Secondly,
I am not clear on what does convertView and parent stand in the methods :

```
public View getGroupView(int groupPosition, boolean isExpanded,
                View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
```

and

```
public View getChildView(int groupPosition, int childPosition,
                boolean isLastChild, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
```

Can anyone explain this significance of them ?

Thirdly,
I wanted to retrieve the Id of the expandableListView from the XML but no ID is created as we are forced to give the ID as `android:id="@android:id/list"` .I mean there are no ID's created in R.id class.

-Adithya

Comment: any help would be really appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, the following seems to be wrong.

```
@Override
public View getChildView(int groupPosition, int childPosition,
        boolean isLastChild, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) 
{
    //TextView childView = null;

    convertView = ((LayoutInflater.from(FoodieActivity.this)).inflate(R.layout.child_list, null));
    **convertView = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.childListId);**

    ((TextView)convertView).setText(getChild(groupPosition, childPosition).toString());

    return convertView;
}
```

Here the convertview will be a layout most probably. You can not cast that to a textView.